# Почему не срабатывает AJAX-скрипт при отправке данных в БД?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, стоит ajax-форма отправки данных в БД. Только со скриптом данные не отправляются, а без скрипта всё хорошо. Что не так со скриптом?

PHP:

```
    <?php
    $data = $_POST;

    if ( isset($data['add']) )
    {
        $posts = R::dispense('posts');

        $posts->head = $data['head'];
        $posts->desc = $data['desc'];

        R::store($posts);
    }
    ?>
```

HTML:

```
    <form action="/" method="POST" id="FormID">
    <input type="text" name="head" />
    <input type="text" name="desc" />

    <button type="submit" name="add">Добавить</button>

    <div id="FormStatus"></div>
```

JS:

```
    $("#FormID").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: form.serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
           $('#FormStatus').text(data);
       }
     });
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: событие submit обрабатывается?

Comment: @SonicMyst похоже что нет. как проверить?

Comment: Открыть консоль разработчика и смотреть туда во все глаза.

Comment: где-нибудь в теле функции прописать  console.log('проверка') - самый простой способ, и посмотреть в консоли разработчика.

Comment: @SonicMyst глянул в консоли, ничё не происходит

Comment: submit должно отлавливаться и обрабатываться

Comment: @SonicMyst дело в том что если убрать скрипт, то всё нормально, только работает с перезагрузкой. а со скриптом — не работает

Comment: значит в скрипте проблема, вам и советую его дебажить. как вообще можно прогить и не знать что такое console.log ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){$("#FormID").submit(function(e) {...});});`